# Can I set up a COM+ application to create "single-use" out-proc servers?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, interop, com-interop

If I write an out-proc COM server myself I can make it "single use" by specifying [`REGCLS_SINGLEUSE` flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in `CoRegisterClassObject()` call.

How can I achieve the same effect when I create a COM+ application and add an in-proc server there so that COM+ surrogate is used and I don't need to write surrogate code? In other words, how can I make the out-proc COM server created by COM+ "single use"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say that I've ever tried it, but it looks as though the COM+ Catalog property `RecycleActivationLimit` of a COM+ Application might do what you want if you set it to 1.